# Proper way to store public and private files in a Cloud

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to find a way to store 1 TB of public and private files and images, which will be expanding every day at a fast rate.

Currently, I use a small NAS connected to our web server to store all our data. For each request, our Web Application can decide if the logged user (based on a cookie) has the permission to view the file or not.

I am currently looking at Google Cloud Storage as a way to store all our data. This solution is ideal for our public files, but I can't find a good way to make it work for our private files.

I am aware Google Cloud Storage allow us to create signed URL which are valid for a limited amount of time, but I am not sure if this is really secure and efficient for a large number of requests.

Another way I can think of would be to have a kind of proxy server which will download the file from the Google Cloud Storage and deliver it to the client if the user has the permission, but won't this be a waste of bandwidth?

In your experience, is there a good way to store this kind of data? It does not have to be Google Cloud Storage, but it has to be easily scalable.

Thanks!

Comment: Signed URLs are the supported way to do this. What security and efficiency concerns do you have?

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how frequently users would need to be authenticated to download files? Signed URLs are very likely to work, but if you need to generate more than, say, a thousand or so per second, you may need to evaluate the cost of that work.

Comment: I am concerned that anyone in possession of the signed URL will have access to the file. Wouldn't that be a kind of security through obscurity and considered bad?

All our users are authenticated. Some images, like the users thumbnails are public, but others like personal PDF and files deliveries have to remain private. I doubt that we will need to sign more than 50 requests/second in the first year of operation.

Comment: I don't see how distribution of the signed URL poses an extra security risk.  Presumably your intent is to grant a user temporary access to object contents.  Once the user has the content, the data is out of your hands and the user could share that content with anyone.  You're vulnerable to this regardless of how the user acquires the content (via a signed URL or some other mechanism).

Comment: I think I figured out how I am going to proceed. The public files will reside in a public bucket and the privates files in a private bucket. Instead of generating a bunch of signed URL which may never be accessed, I will add a "download" link that will verify the identity and permissions of the user in our Web Application. If the user has access, this link will generate the signed URL and redirect the user to it. The signed URL will have a very short time to live, so it should not be shared or cause any security issue that I can think of. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A private bucket is really the best way to segregate your non-public files. I have mine set up in an ASP.NET application that requires user authorization, so my download script authenticates the account and then serves the files by bucket and file name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made a few changes to my application logic and this is what I ended up doing. I am still wondering if the application should download the file from the private bucket and serve it to the user or if I should generate a signed URL with a short time to live and redirect the user to it.

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't need to authenticate or authorize the user at that point, why not just let the application download it and the user's browser handle it according to the user's preference? You can also name the file in your download code so the user does not see its cloud storage address.